# Common perpendicular

Tags: geometry

> In the Poincare plane $\mathbb{H}$ show that two distinct type $1$ lines are parallel but do not have a common perpendicular.

Let $\mathbb{H}= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y > 0 \}.$

A type $1$ line is any subset of the Poincare plane $\mathbb{H}$ of the form $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{H}|x=a\}$.

I understand why they are parallel, but why do they not have a common perpendicular?

Comment: What's a "type $I$" line?

Comment: @Ted I have edited. It is a type $1$ line of the Poincare plane.

Comment: A plausibility argument, not a proof: two such lines (they are geodesics, not horocycles) get close and closer as you go upwards, “meeting” at $i\infty$, with angle zero. If there were a common perpendicular, you’d have a “triangle” with sum of the angles equal to $\pi$, and thus with area zero.

Comment: i am studying a half plane model with $x>0$ this why i did this silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

A better proof than my comment: Consider two lines (geodesics) with a common perpendicular, say running from $p\in\ell$ to $p'\in\ell'$. The segment $pp'$ is shortest in length among all segments running from $\ell$ to $\ell'$. But there is no shortest segment between two Type 1 lines, because they get closer and closer to each other as you go up.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you assumed that in order to have a common perpendicular then the common perpendicular must be the shortest length among all segments between the two lines. And since typle $1$ lines doesn't have a shortest segment thus it has no common perpendicular?

Comment: Just so. As you say, a pair of Type1 lines have no shortest distance between them, as I hope you’ve seen.